# Home Server/NAS Plagued by random crashes

Tags: debian, kernel, docker, samba, nfs

I'm here to get help for an issue which has been plaguing me for a year. I'm using HP Elitedesk 800 G3 i5-7500 as my Home Server/NAS.

I have the latest Debian 12 (Bookworm) on it. I'm running my services on it as Docker Containers, and for the sharing part I have set up both NFS and SAMBA Shares.

The problem is that every random day/time the system freezes up and becomes unresponsive.

This is the journalctl log from the last crash:
https://pastebin.com/vGbSfYuq

Complete `dmesg` output:
https://pastebin.com/x6GKs4LR

Smartctl of both drives:
https://pastebin.com/9PgTU2ur

#### Here is the system specs:

```
Host: server Kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Console: pty pts/3 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: HP product: HP EliteDesk 800 G3 SFF
    v: N/A
  Mobo: HP model: 8299 v: KBC Version 06.29
    UEFI: HP v: P01 Ver. 02.48
    date: 10/05/2023
CPU:
  Info: quad core Intel Core i5-7500 [MCP] speed (MHz):
    avg: 800 min/max: 800/3800
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.7 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    tty: 65x37 resolution: 1920x1080
  API: OpenGL Message: GL data unavailable in console for
    root.
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM driver: e1000e
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: N/A
  Device-3: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB
    driver: btusb
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.87 TiB used: 832.97 GiB (21.0%)
Info:
  Processes: 381 Uptime: 1d 4h 21m Memory: 7.63 GiB
  used: 3.03 GiB (39.6%) Init: systemd target: graphical (5)
  Shell: Sudo inxi: 3.3.26
```

I have already ran memtest86++ for 14h on this RAM stick, and 0 errors were found.

I have a Kingston NV2 250GB NVMe SSD as boot drive, one WD Blue 4TB 3.5" HDD for data, and a single 8GB DDR4-2400MHZ RAM. I can post any further information if required.

Kindly help me solve this issue. I don't want to lose my precious data by hard-reseting the system after every crash.

---

[2024-03-19] It happened again. This time the issue started by a process `certbot` running inside a Docker Container called SWAG (`linuxserver/swag`).

Here is the full journal log:
https://pastebin.com/8R886upg

This time the system was in responsive state; but when I tried to reboot, it got stuck at the end of the reboot process.

---

[2024-03-24] Another crash happened. Log:
https://pastebin.com/vqVUD92Z

---

[2024-02-04] I have stopped all the Docker Containers, even masked `docker.socket` and `docker.service` to fully disable Docker.

Even after all this, it crashed again.
Log: https://pastebin.com/hfHXj01a

Regards~

Comment: Have you looked at the logs to check with issues with services, applications and/or the system and the output of `dmesg` for issues with the drives? Add that information to the question so that you can get help. Do not post it in the comments?

Comment: I have checked all the containers, non of them have any error, and are working smooth.

Comment: You said that the system was freezing and becoming unresponsive, not the containers. Check the system logs and `dmesg` on the system itself and add that to the question.

Comment: I have added the complete `dmesg` output. Yes, fully unresponsive, I can't even do anything on the console. I also did fresh install of the OS last year, but same issue. Though I'm persisting my Containers Config + Data.

Comment: Check the power supply.

Comment: Tested with different Power Supply too, didn't fix the problem. @ChrisDavies Alright mate, tried to fixed it, hope it is better now.